# SQL Query is too complex, yet seems very simple

Tags: sql, long-integer

I recently developed a model through SAS/KXen and exported this score code script in SQL.  However, I'm getting a "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables. (Error 3071)" 
 error code, yet this script seems simple enough (just a lot of case whens).  Any ideas to rectify the problem? Thank you:

-- KXEN Analytic Framework - IXI Corp - Equifax_US_Amendment 1_2011_06_30 - Itam Media - - Copyright KXEN (c) 1999-2011 - Model built in 5.1.4 - Model Name is auto_digital_targets_model: Auto Trigger (Month Added) - Model Version is 1

```
SELECT $Key, "rr_auto", CAST( (CASE 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -1.077823785821e0 THEN 6.05306179145e-3
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -7.882377294631e-2 THEN 6.05306179145e-3
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -7.782378582091e-2 THEN  ( 1.353029818544e-3*"rr_auto"+6.159712720187e-3 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -2.27776053868e-2 THEN  ( 2.457958732379e-5*"rr_auto"+6.056327680634e-3 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -2.27225048152e-2 THEN  ( 2.453076886879e1*"rr_auto"+5.648081862521e-1 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -2.239074958722e-2 THEN  ( 4.074267027032e0*"rr_auto"+9.998502008548e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -2.122812183221e-2 THEN  ( 3.317444508635e-1*"rr_auto"+1.618709683277e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -1.93194152634e-2 THEN  ( 2.02071555915e-1*"rr_auto"+1.343438352374e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -1.880207986003e-2 THEN  ( 2.750673996089e0*"rr_auto"+6.26719178928e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -1.629110457901e-2 THEN  ( 5.667204500391e-1*"rr_auto"+2.160902706983e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -1.422586845977e-2 THEN  ( 8.377498048977e-1*"rr_auto"+2.602439734411e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -1.272245032419e-2 THEN  ( 1.150811683736e0*"rr_auto"+3.047797758284e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -1.040443748766e-2 THEN  ( 4.840967408216e-1*"rr_auto"+2.199572317408e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -9.092699548129e-3 THEN  ( 8.554623797399e-1*"rr_auto"+2.585957746292e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -7.776715513431e-3 THEN  ( 8.499508924389e-1*"rr_auto"+2.580946310972e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -7.067411649177e-3 THEN  ( 1.57692895964e0*"rr_auto"+3.146297199262e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -6.189206328952e-3 THEN  ( 1.028690319931e0*"rr_auto"+2.758833836143e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -5.106390124994e-3 THEN  ( 8.343071599086e-1*"rr_auto"+2.638525893334e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -4.068712552393e-3 THEN  ( 9.084700249121e-1*"rr_auto"+2.676396419647e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -3.236476389088e-3 THEN  ( 1.132730121325e0*"rr_auto"+2.767641630835e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -2.311112848156e-3 THEN  ( 9.162096194071e-1*"rr_auto"+2.697565065093e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -1.484466429351e-3 THEN  ( 1.025622271342e0*"rr_auto"+2.722851673069e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -6.582919879849e-4 THEN  ( 1.026794442297e0*"rr_auto"+2.723025679085e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= -2.372768614338e-4 THEN  ( 2.014918874085e0*"rr_auto"+2.788074106867e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 7.348116300255e-4 THEN  ( 3.779561021206e-1*"rr_auto"+2.749231131023e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 1.466972506743e-3 THEN  ( 5.018115401022e-1*"rr_auto"+2.740130213251e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 1.773626724415e-3 THEN  ( 2.860591190964e0*"rr_auto"+2.394106082303e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 2.233186453451e-3 THEN  ( 1.908810320657e0*"rr_auto"+2.562915529258e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 3.00010379386e-3 THEN  ( 6.854086624086e-1*"rr_auto"+2.83612270689e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 3.936044386394e-3 THEN  ( 5.616294374467e-1*"rr_auto"+2.873257635351e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 4.478472197817e-3 THEN  ( 1.672101099827e0*"rr_auto"+2.436172170527e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 5.028307559689e-3 THEN  ( 1.649574041524e0*"rr_auto"+2.446260828431e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 5.850721137488e-3 THEN  ( 7.37321002719e-1*"rr_auto"+2.904968801315e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 6.001886640999e-3 THEN  ( 4.011383482005e0*"rr_auto"+9.894094200759e-3 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 6.746515643618e-3 THEN  ( 1.653178226231e-1*"rr_auto"+3.297770584155e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 7.617596362912e-3 THEN  ( 1.413192172072e-1*"rr_auto"+3.313961256843e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 7.733833416175e-3 THEN  ( 7.936496738217e0*"rr_auto"-2.62408254121e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 8.391316551827e-3 THEN  ( 1.403100618187e0*"rr_auto"+2.428730648814e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 9.277818407042e-3 THEN  ( 7.717893009392e-1*"rr_auto"+2.95848332808e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 9.921191372171e-3 THEN  ( 1.063446374344e0*"rr_auto"+2.68788948332e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 1.04156843028e-2 THEN  ( 1.800201154244e0*"rr_auto"+1.956941703499e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 1.158256334531e-2 THEN  ( 7.628783379167e-1*"rr_auto"+3.037383363673e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 1.235526014615e-2 THEN  ( 1.739757568828e0*"rr_auto"+1.905907783277e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 1.344232502489e-2 THEN  ( 1.236637420602e0*"rr_auto"+2.527525311767e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 1.446073277534e-2 THEN  ( 1.408996524257e0*"rr_auto"+2.295834774894e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 1.670931082955e-2 THEN  ( 6.381512876404e-1*"rr_auto"+3.410532701834e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 1.773094271753e-2 THEN  ( 3.091367987252e0*"rr_auto"-6.886208815554e-3 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 2.149117445603e-2 THEN  ( 8.399057113687e-1*"rr_auto"+3.303431731419e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 2.399923014126e-2 THEN  ( 1.887927909042e0*"rr_auto"+1.051109991042e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 2.403763415355e-2 THEN  ( 1.232951466039e2*"rr_auto"-2.903167468286e0 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 6.240324243199e-2 THEN  ( 1.235421072765e-4*"rr_auto"+6.055195607717e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 6.340324247949e-2 THEN  ( 4.739767868535e-3*"rr_auto"+6.026388866803e-2 ) 
WHEN "rr_auto" <= 1.062403242432e0 THEN 6.05644052721e-2
WHEN "rr_auto" > 1.062403232432e0 THEN 6.05644052721e-2
WHEN "rr_auto" >= 1.562403222432e0 THEN 6.05644052721e-2
ELSE 0.0e0
END)  AS FLOAT )
AS PROBA0 
FROM 
(
SELECT $Key, 
( 5.881871083571e-3 + 
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "Comp360" IS NULL ) THEN 4.935327682215e-3
WHEN "Comp360" < 1.418e3 THEN -9.487857723034e-3
WHEN "Comp360" <= 3.73200624627e4 THEN  ( 3.909023382895e-8*"Comp360"-9.543287674603e-3 ) 
WHEN "Comp360" <= 3.735600000001e4 THEN  ( 8.871132410687e-5*"Comp360"-3.318796594523e0 ) 
WHEN "Comp360" <= 4.329428094367e4 THEN  ( 5.757205724121e-7*"Comp360"-2.640298888932e-2 ) 
WHEN "Comp360" <= 5.366200000001e4 THEN  ( 2.151378961397e-7*"Comp360"-1.079182119937e-2 ) 
WHEN "Comp360" <= 5.5568715698e4 THEN  ( 9.963450072002e-7*"Comp360"-5.27129571931e-2 ) 
WHEN "Comp360" <= 7.363500000001e4 THEN  ( 4.97528001222e-8*"Comp360"-1.120439560443e-4 ) 
WHEN "Comp360" <= 7.456136504401e4 THEN  ( 2.470352068076e-7*"Comp360"-1.463893397232e-2 ) 
WHEN "Comp360" <= 1.0e6 THEN  ( 3.909023382895e-8*"Comp360"+8.657270670023e-4 ) 
WHEN "Comp360" >= 1.0e6 THEN 3.995596089595e-2
ELSE 3.0421122029e-3
END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "DSIIndex" IS NULL ) THEN -1.22528641747e-3
WHEN "DSIIndex" < 1.0e0 THEN -4.347321884497e-3
WHEN "DSIIndex" <= 6.493600083397e1 THEN  ( 1.895933608395e-7*"DSIIndex"-4.347511477858e-3 ) 
WHEN "DSIIndex" <= 6.500000001e1 THEN  ( 2.415957577851e-2*"DSIIndex"-1.573161432703e0 ) 
WHEN "DSIIndex" <= 1.172985795211e2 THEN  ( 2.975408294321e-5*"DSIIndex"-4.723022491584e-3 ) 
WHEN "DSIIndex" <= 2.1100000001e2 THEN  ( 9.399555019836e-6*"DSIIndex"-2.335465279553e-3 ) 
WHEN "DSIIndex" <= 2.289725274846e2 THEN  ( 4.820657323843e-5*"DSIIndex"-1.052374612368e-2 ) 
WHEN "DSIIndex" <= 2.6700000001e2 THEN  ( 1.09151102402e-5*"DSIIndex"-1.985025587747e-3 ) 
WHEN "DSIIndex" <= 2.677330000448e2 THEN  ( 5.566210791432e-4*"DSIIndex"-1.476885192848e-1 ) 
WHEN "DSIIndex" <= 1.00000000001e3 THEN  ( 1.895933608395e-7*"DSIIndex"+1.286551717494e-3 ) 
WHEN "DSIIndex" >= 9.9999999999e2 THEN 1.476145078333e-3
ELSE 1.342517033075e-3
END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "Bal_RetailCredit_New" IS NULL ) THEN 3.435891076066e-4
WHEN "Bal_RetailCredit_New" < 0.0e0 THEN -1.027663996908e-3
WHEN "Bal_RetailCredit_New" <= 2.097900028037e1 THEN  ( 1.695549928681e-8*"Bal_RetailCredit_New"-1.027663996908e-3 ) 
WHEN "Bal_RetailCredit_New" <= 2.100000001e1 THEN  ( 2.950669720501e-2*"Bal_RetailCredit_New"-6.200483169289e-1 ) 
WHEN "Bal_RetailCredit_New" <= 1.017480518373e2 THEN  ( 7.690605743411e-6*"Bal_RetailCredit_New"-5.691783444176e-4 ) 
WHEN "Bal_RetailCredit_New" <= 1.7000000001e2 THEN  ( 1.075773997763e-5*"Bal_RetailCredit_New"-8.812532774423e-4 ) 
WHEN "Bal_RetailCredit_New" <= 7.17208026001e2 THEN  ( 1.35662785556e-6*"Bal_RetailCredit_New"+7.169357833101e-4 ) 
WHEN "Bal_RetailCredit_New" <= 5.47378e5 THEN  ( 1.69554992868e-8*"Bal_RetailCredit_New"+1.677759549427e-3 ) 
WHEN "Bal_RetailCredit_New" >= 5.47378e5 THEN 1.095882683804e-2
ELSE 3.435891076066e-4
END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "Bal_OtherNonMortgage_New" IS NULL ) THEN 6.49070492785e-4
WHEN "Bal_OtherNonMortgage_New" < 0.0e0 THEN -9.492489235445e-4
WHEN "Bal_OtherNonMortgage_New" <= 3.196800042199e1 THEN  ( -2.865089974917e-8*"Bal_OtherNonMortgage_New"-9.492489235445e-4 ) 
WHEN "Bal_OtherNonMortgage_New" <= 3.200000001e1 THEN  ( 4.305535039747e-2*"Bal_OtherNonMortgage_New"-1.37734362408e0 ) 
WHEN "Bal_OtherNonMortgage_New" <= 3.949024186059e3 THEN  ( 3.230840719637e-7*"Bal_OtherNonMortgage_New"+4.17249948639e-4 ) 
WHEN "Bal_OtherNonMortgage_New" <= 3.917056e6 THEN  ( -2.865089974917e-8*"Bal_OtherNonMortgage_New"+1.806259859012e-3 ) 
WHEN "Bal_OtherNonMortgage_New" >= 3.917056e6 THEN -1.104209189089e-1
ELSE 6.49070492785e-4
END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "HH_AutoFin" IS NULL ) THEN 1.488472474192e-4
WHEN "HH_AutoFin" < 0.0e0 THEN -4.710736071749e-3
WHEN "HH_AutoFin" <= 9.990000138746e0 THEN  ( 1.201538430985e-4*"HH_AutoFin"-4.710736071749e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoFin" <= 1.000000001e1 THEN  ( 6.400562921613e-2*"HH_AutoFin"-6.429266432734e-1 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoFin" <= 1.392892551578e1 THEN  ( 2.827546681306e-4*"HH_AutoFin"-5.697897793341e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoFin" <= 2.200000001e1 THEN  ( 1.586846072613e-4*"HH_AutoFin"-3.969735157996e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoFin" <= 2.792193557951e1 THEN  ( 1.726678673103e-4*"HH_AutoFin"-4.277366879072e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoFin" <= 3.300000001e1 THEN  ( 1.915716060023e-4*"HH_AutoFin"-4.805195852855e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoFin" <= 3.306700001318e1 THEN  ( 5.533049130884e-3*"HH_AutoFin"-1.81073954174e-1 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoFin" <= 1.0000000001e2 THEN  ( 1.201538430985e-4*"HH_AutoFin"-2.085745675522e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoFin" >= 9.999999999e1 THEN 9.929638634331e-3
ELSE 1.488472474192e-4
END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "HH_AutoBnk" IS NULL ) THEN -1.614032285829e-4
WHEN "HH_AutoBnk" < 0.0e0 THEN -1.838399331938e-3
WHEN "HH_AutoBnk" <= 1.298700017737e1 THEN  ( 1.815003168977e-4*"HH_AutoBnk"-1.838399331938e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoBnk" <= 1.300000001e1 THEN  ( -6.04737135335e-2*"HH_AutoBnk"+7.85890873095e-1 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoBnk" <= 1.583695456651e1 THEN  ( -9.644126182477e-5*"HH_AutoBnk"+9.863335632526e-4 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoBnk" <= 2.000000001e1 THEN  ( 5.242714728826e-5*"HH_AutoBnk"-1.371288666771e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoBnk" <= 2.424793984083e1 THEN  ( 5.500665361205e-5*"HH_AutoBnk"-1.422878793247e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoBnk" <= 2.800000001e1 THEN  ( 1.936191250225e-5*"HH_AutoBnk"-5.58567255531e-4 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoBnk" <= 3.570272726119e1 THEN  ( 1.025214008351e-4*"HH_AutoBnk"-2.887032928851e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoBnk" <= 4.100000001e1 THEN  ( 1.450836551356e-5*"HH_AutoBnk"+2.552724657839e-4 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoBnk" <= 4.10590000128e1 THEN  ( -1.48117517394e-2*"HH_AutoBnk"+6.081319367672e-1 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoBnk" <= 1.0000000001e2 THEN  ( 1.815003168977e-4*"HH_AutoBnk"-7.475999454305e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_AutoBnk" >= 9.999999999e1 THEN 1.067403223547e-2
ELSE -1.614032285829e-4
END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "HH_FMOther" IS NULL ) THEN -1.069677183384e-4
WHEN "HH_FMOther" < 0.0e0 THEN 1.484348281833e-3
WHEN "HH_FMOther" <= 1.398600019024e1 THEN  ( -5.691356379979e-5*"HH_FMOther"+1.484348281833e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_FMOther" <= 1.400000001e1 THEN  ( -1.381375944085e-2*"HH_FMOther"+1.938875971978e-1 ) 
WHEN "HH_FMOther" <= 1.728919387302e1 THEN  ( -1.15466926935e-4*"HH_FMOther"+2.111502003043e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_FMOther" <= 2.800000001e1 THEN  ( -6.243543751057e-5*"HH_FMOther"+1.194630301539e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_FMOther" <= 3.189892742845e1 THEN  ( -7.208279176467e-5*"HH_FMOther"+1.464756220654e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_FMOther" <= 3.600000001e1 THEN  ( -7.062423979564e-5*"HH_FMOther"+1.418229977258e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_FMOther" <= 3.606400001304e1 THEN  ( -9.354834814612e-4*"HH_FMOther"+3.255316267722e-2 ) 
WHEN "HH_FMOther" <= 1.0000000001e2 THEN  ( -5.691356379979e-5*"HH_FMOther"+8.684171640062e-4 ) 
WHEN "HH_FMOther" >= 9.999999999e1 THEN -4.822939215973e-3
ELSE -1.069677183384e-4
END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "HH_MortgageCredit" IS NULL ) THEN -1.456794544127e-5
WHEN "HH_MortgageCredit" < 0.0e0 THEN -8.384990197329e-4
WHEN "HH_MortgageCredit" <= 2.297700030612e1 THEN  ( 1.325824884976e-5*"HH_MortgageCredit"-8.384990197329e-4 ) 
WHEN "HH_MortgageCredit" <= 2.300000001e1 THEN  ( 2.714272371401e-3*"HH_MortgageCredit"-6.28997013134e-2 ) 
WHEN "HH_MortgageCredit" <= 3.589630763069e1 THEN  ( 1.807532725954e-5*"HH_MortgageCredit"-8.871692981523e-4 ) 
WHEN "HH_MortgageCredit" <= 5.600000001e1 THEN  ( 1.524051891743e-5*"HH_MortgageCredit"-7.854101458584e-4 ) 
WHEN "HH_MortgageCredit" <= 6.37657348849e1 THEN  ( 1.838988781184e-5*"HH_MortgageCredit"-9.617748039452e-4 ) 
WHEN "HH_MortgageCredit" <= 7.000000001e1 THEN  ( 2.122077144275e-5*"HH_MortgageCredit"-1.142288179015e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_MortgageCredit" <= 7.003000001142e1 THEN  ( 1.667940733899e-3*"HH_MortgageCredit"-1.16412685551e-1 ) 
WHEN "HH_MortgageCredit" <= 1.0000000001e2 THEN  ( 1.325824884976e-5*"HH_MortgageCredit"-5.352711205967e-4 ) 
WHEN "HH_MortgageCredit" >= 9.999999999e1 THEN 7.905537643791e-4
ELSE -1.456794544127e-5
END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "HH_1stMortgageCredit_NL12" IS NULL ) THEN -3.851479335309e-4
WHEN "HH_1stMortgageCredit_NL12" < 0.0e0 THEN -5.924051677173e-4
WHEN "HH_1stMortgageCredit_NL12" <= 5.994000087248e0 THEN  ( 1.328845709937e-4*"HH_1stMortgageCredit_NL12"-5.924051677173e-4 ) 
WHEN "HH_1stMortgageCredit_NL12" <= 6.00000001e0 THEN  ( -5.29232194671e-2*"HH_1stMortgageCredit_NL12"+3.174258865351e-1 ) 
WHEN "HH_1stMortgageCredit_NL12" <= 6.094000014465e0 THEN  ( -3.253631499761e-3*"HH_1stMortgageCredit_NL12"+1.940835873104e-2 ) 
WHEN "HH_1stMortgageCredit_NL12" <= 1.0000000001e2 THEN  ( 1.328845709937e-4*"HH_1stMortgageCredit_NL12"-1.229070219259e-3 ) 
WHEN "HH_1stMortgageCredit_NL12" >= 9.999999999e1 THEN 1.205938688011e-2
ELSE -3.851479335309e-4
END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit" IS NULL ) THEN -7.682563890863e-5
WHEN "AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit" < 2.0e0 THEN 4.813545150812e-3
WHEN "AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit" <= 7.392800093697e1 THEN  ( -6.861529764345e-5*"AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit"+4.950775746099e-3 ) 
WHEN "AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit" <= 7.400000001e1 THEN  ( 2.788005779118e-3*"AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit"-2.062335098648e-1 ) 
WHEN "AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit" <= 9.715412288377e1 THEN  ( -5.973247057019e-5*"AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit"+4.499120612198e-3 ) 
WHEN "AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit" <= 1.0700000001e2 THEN  ( -1.949069486607e-5*"AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit"+5.894661907816e-4 ) 
WHEN "AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit" <= 1.07316000025e2 THEN  ( 1.46200109428e-3*"AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit"-1.579301552478e-1 ) 
WHEN "AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit" <= 4.2300000001e2 THEN  ( -6.861529764345e-5*"AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit"+6.329473490782e-3 ) 
WHEN "AvgMoB_TotalAllCredit" >= 4.2299999999e2 THEN -2.26947974124e-2
ELSE -7.682563890863e-5
END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "NA_AutoBank" IS NULL ) THEN 2.903024345148e-4
WHEN "NA_AutoBank" < 0.0e0 THEN -3.829896504652e-3
WHEN "NA_AutoBank" <= 1.298700116737e-1 THEN  ( -3.169363530011e-4*"NA_AutoBank"-3.829896504652e-3 ) 
WHEN "NA_AutoBank" <= 1.3000001e-1 THEN  ( 1.294408334764e1*"NA_AutoBank"-1.684919183051e0 ) 
WHEN "NA_AutoBank" <= 2.091882296263e-1 THEN  ( 2.093307254777e-2*"NA_AutoBank"-4.909647289856e-3 ) 
WHEN "NA_AutoBank" <= 3.2000001e-1 THEN  ( 1.053502926052e-2*"NA_AutoBank"-2.734499126998e-3 ) 
WHEN "NA_AutoBank" <= 3.849008699287e-1 THEN  ( 1.821171845231e-2*"NA_AutoBank"-5.191039668372e-3 ) 
WHEN "NA_AutoBank" <= 4.7000001e-1 THEN  ( 1.045997845179e-2*"NA_AutoBank"-2.207388276225e-3 ) 
WHEN "NA_AutoBank" <= 5.308603385687e-1 THEN  ( 1.475209472318e-2*"NA_AutoBank"-4.224682923781e-3 ) 
WHEN "NA_AutoBank" <= 5.7000001e-1 THEN  ( 3.611812983299e-2*"NA_AutoBank"-1.556706334239e-2 ) 
WHEN "NA_AutoBank" <= 6.744300149602e-1 THEN  ( 1.333868417139e-2*"NA_AutoBank"-2.582779315276e-3 ) 
WHEN "NA_AutoBank" <= 1.0500000001e2 THEN  ( -3.169363530011e-4*"NA_AutoBank"+6.626980902726e-3 ) 
WHEN "NA_AutoBank" >= 1.0499999999e2 THEN -2.665133616239e-2
ELSE 2.903024345148e-4
END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "Cty" IS NULL ) THEN -1.782382804934e-3
WHEN "Cty" < 0.0e0 THEN 1.962640547298e-4
WHEN "Cty" > 1.9e1 THEN -6.707198221185e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 0.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN 1.962640547298e-4
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 1.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -1.335104218808e-4
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 2.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -4.632848984915e-4
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 3.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -7.930593751021e-4
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 4.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -1.122833851713e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 5.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -1.452608328323e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 6.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -1.782382804934e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 7.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -2.318538385233e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 8.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -2.648312861844e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 9.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -2.978087338455e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 1.0e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -3.307861815065e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 1.1e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -3.637636291676e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 1.2e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -3.967410768287e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 1.3e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -4.297185244897e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 1.4e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -4.626959721508e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 1.5e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -4.956734198119e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 1.6e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -5.286508674729e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 1.7e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -6.047649267963e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 1.8e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -6.377423744574e-3
WHEN ABS( "Cty" - 1.9e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -6.707198221185e-3
WHEN "Cty" >= 0.0e0 AND "Cty" <= 6.0e0 THEN -4.75035309443e-3
WHEN "Cty" >= 7.0e0 AND "Cty" <= 1.6e1 THEN -4.956734198119e-3
WHEN "Cty" >= 1.7e1 AND "Cty" <= 1.9e1 THEN -5.388100314742e-3
ELSE -4.956734198119e-3
END) AS FLOAT )+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "Den" IS NULL ) THEN -1.370866855927e-3
WHEN "Den" < 0.0e0 THEN 1.187397664919e-4
WHEN "Den" > 1.9e1 THEN -4.731455220138e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 0.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN 1.187397664919e-4
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 1.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -1.222356536684e-4
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 2.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -3.632110738288e-4
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 3.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -6.041864939891e-4
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 4.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -8.451619141494e-4
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 5.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -1.08613733431e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 6.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -1.370866855927e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 7.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -1.611842276087e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 8.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -1.852817696247e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 9.0e0 ) < 10e-9 THEN -2.170563863785e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 1.0e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -2.411539283945e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 1.1e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -2.652514704105e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 1.2e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -2.893490124266e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 1.3e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -3.285602699176e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 1.4e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -3.526578119336e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 1.5e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -3.767553539497e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 1.6e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -4.008528959657e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 1.7e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -4.249504379817e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 1.8e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -4.490479799978e-3
WHEN ABS( "Den" - 1.9e1 ) < 10e-9 THEN -4.731455220138e-3
WHEN "Den" >= 0.0e0 AND "Den" <= 5.0e0 THEN -1.32711275447e-3
WHEN "Den" >= 6.0e0 AND "Den" <= 8.0e0 THEN -1.370866855927e-3
WHEN "Den" >= 9.0e0 AND "Den" <= 1.2e1 THEN -1.447637603304e-3
WHEN "Den" >= 1.3e1 AND "Den" <= 1.9e1 THEN -1.598774758054e-3
ELSE -1.370866855927e-3
END) AS FLOAT )+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "OM_Score_CompBank" IS NULL ) THEN 2.067576391454e-3
WHEN "OM_Score_CompBank" < -1.83990421043e1 THEN 5.862160932523e-3
WHEN "OM_Score_CompBank" <= 5.407811559579e1 THEN  ( -7.321353908529e-5*"OM_Score_CompBank"+4.515101944288e-3 ) 
WHEN "OM_Score_CompBank" <= 5.41506643682e1 THEN  ( -8.486274509202e-3*"OM_Score_CompBank"+4.594775855165e-1 ) 
WHEN "OM_Score_CompBank" <= 5.988691655253e1 THEN  ( -1.796170279856e-4*"OM_Score_CompBank"+9.666564312643e-3 ) 
WHEN "OM_Score_CompBank" <= 6.60103895187e1 THEN  ( -1.66585554025e-4*"OM_Score_CompBank"+8.88614951914e-3 ) 
WHEN "OM_Score_CompBank" <= 6.608293388151e1 THEN  ( -7.954749568922e-3*"OM_Score_CompBank"+5.229858897002e-1 ) 
WHEN "OM_Score_CompBank" <= 1.38554748887e2 THEN  ( -7.321353908529e-5*"OM_Score_CompBank"+2.150865434479e-3 ) 
WHEN "OM_Score_CompBank" >= 1.38554748867e2 THEN -7.99321808788e-3
ELSE 8.430977645999e-4
END) AS FLOAT)+
CAST( (CASE 
WHEN ( "month" IS NULL OR "month" = ''  ) THEN -2.771172542423e-3
WHEN "month" IN('01', '02', '03', '04', '05')  THEN 2.624553958278e-3
WHEN "month" IN('06', '12')  THEN 3.782250849016e-4
ELSE -2.771172542423e-3
END) AS FLOAT )
) AS "rr_auto"
FROM $Dataset
) TMPTABLE0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a group of temp tables/ table variables, toss the comparison and calculation constants inside, and then query against the values in those tables.  I would imagine that would be a lot easier to read as well.

Comment: @user1456828, I would not do as TEMP tables, but as PERMANENT tables (ie: a lookup table. Have low-range, high-range to qualify, multiValue, addValue) as columns once the join within range record is found.